# Extjs building form on metadata

Tags: json, extjs, model-view-controller, dynamic

I will build a FormPanel with ExtJs 4 configured by metadata received from server. The meta data (json array) looks like this:

```
   {
      "metaData": {
      [
        {
           "allowBlank:": false, 
           "fieldLabel:": "labelText1", 
           "name:": "labelName1", 
           "emptyText:": "null"
        },
        {
           "allowBlank:": false, 
           "fieldLabel:": "labelText1", 
           "name:": "labelName1", 
           "emptyText:": "null"
        }
     ]
  },
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Unknown"
}
```

Is it possible to create the form on runtime with the given json array? So yes, can you give a tutorial or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely [possible](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ot8). Basically you use your metadata as `items` and create the form at any time:

```js
var metadata = [
        {
           "allowBlank": false, 
           "fieldLabel": "labelText1", 
           "name": "labelName1", 
           "emptyText": null
        },
        {
           "allowBlank": false, 
           "fieldLabel": "labelText1", 
           "name": "labelName1", 
           "emptyText": null
        }
     ];
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: metadata
});
```

Just make sure the metadata JSON is correct, remove colons from property names etc. ("`fieldLabel`" it should be, not "`fieldLabel:`").

Comment: Thanks for your good example. But how can I used your example by using Ext.define? When tried I got a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" error.

Comment: **how can I used your example by using Ext.define?**

Use it as normal to define your say `My.form.Panel` but just don't specify `items`. Then use `Ext.create('My.form.Panel')` as in my example.

**I got a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"**

That's a separate issue. I suggest you post another question and provide details to seek help.

**can you create the fields from a store by using something like items**

Sure you can — it does not matter where your metadata comes from. You just need to make sure it's correctly formed before passing it as `items` to your panel.